# CakePHP Render a View inside home.ctp

Tags: cakephp

My version of Cake: 2.4.7

I am attempting to allow users to register an account from within home.ctp using CakePHP. I have a view entitled users/add, which is a simple user registration form. What is the best way to then render this view inside a page (home.ctp)?

My add function code:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

My code for the view:

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Add User'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    echo $this->Form->input('email');
    //echo $this->Form->input('role');
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<h3><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></h3>
<ul>

    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Users'), array('action' => 'index')); ?></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

From what I have found, the best method may be to utilize an element, however I am very new to Cake and am not sure how to go about rendering the view inside an element.

EDIT: I have copied my users/add.ctp code and pasted it into an element, and am able to render this element on the home page. How am I then able to have this form interact with the Users controller, so that the user is actually added when the form is submitted?

Comment: The docs are pretty clear on how elements work, so what exactly is that you don't understand? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: Hey Feek, having $this->Form->create('User');... will allow the form to be posted to users/add by default.

Comment: Even so, you can $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add', ....

Comment: here is how you can render to a specific view or to element.. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#interacting-with-views

Comment: ahh thank you @Antuan! It required me adding array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add'));